# calculates the average value contained in a file for every 16 seconds

Tags: bash, shell

I have a big file "values.txt" in which there are a lot of values. These values ​​can be found in the file valeur.txt as follow :

```
File:  "values.txt"
************************************************** *****************************************
2
14
18
20
23
.
.
.
24
******************************************************************************************
```

I want to write a script that calculate the average of values ​​read from the file values.txt for every 16 seconds

i e : After each 16 seconds I will calculate the average of values ​​that I have read in the file values.txt

for exmpl :

To read the file "value.txt", we will take (16 * 4 = 64) seconds.
So,  when the exuction of script is finished,  it must show  4 values.  because  every 16 seconds it will calculate an average.

I tried to do things but the concept of time (16 seconds) I still can't manage it

---

```
let "i=0"    
let"cum=0"

while read var   
do  
if [timer] # how I could control the period of 16 seconde ?  
then  
let "i = i +1"  
let "cum = cum + var"  
else  # 16 seconds have elapsed, so i calculate the averag   
let  "avrg_var= cum /i" 
echo "$avrg_var">> new_file.txt
fi 
done < values.txt
```

---

Thank you in advance for your answers and suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while :
do
    let "i=0"
    let "cum=0"
    while read var
    do
        let "i = i +1"
        let "cum = cum + var"
    done < /tmp/values.txt 

    let "avrg_var= cum /i"

    echo "$avrg_var">> new_file.txt

    sleep 16
done
```

This doesn't work on a timer, just sleeps 16 seconds between runs.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script that averages the values once, and then you can run your script with the [watch](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/watch-command-examples/) command assuming your on a *nix based system. The default is 2 seconds but you can change it to what ever you want and it will repeatedly run in the terminal until canceled